# Understanding the tangent of an $\arcsin(2x)$-- where to start

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm having difficulty seeing where to start the problem of $\tan(\arcsin(2x))$ where x is restricted to $0\leq x \leq1/2$.

Not clear as to first step even.

Comment: The usual method is to draw a right triangle where one angle is $\arcsin(2x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan  (arcsin(2x))=\frac { \sin { \left( arcsin(2x) \right)  }  }{ \cos { \left( arcsin(2x) \right)  }  } =\frac { 2x }{ \sqrt { 1-{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( \arcsin { \left( 2x \right)  }  \right)  }  } }  } =\frac { 2x }{ \sqrt { 1-{ 4{ x }^{ 2 } } }  }  $$

Answer (score 0):

One may write, for $0<x<\frac12$,
$$
\tan\left(\arcsin(2x) \right)=\frac{\sin\left(\arcsin(2x) \right)}{\cos\left(\arcsin(2x) \right)}=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(\arcsin(2x) \right)}}=\cdots.
$$

Comment: it would seem to me that the triangle in the x-y plane has vertices at: (0,0) and (2x,0) and $(2x,\sqrt(1-4x^2)$. If this is the triangle, isn't the tan of that $\sqrt(1-4x^2) / 2x$  ??